# What is the meaning of the name in the bottom-right-corner?

Tags: discussion

I read a question in https://math.stackexchange.com/ and notice a username in the bottom-right-corner.
It is the name of the person who asked the question?
Not necessarily.
It is the name who answered the question and it was accepted?
Not necessarily.
It is the name of the person who (re)edited the original question?
Not necessarily.
I think it must be name of the person who asked the question. Is it possible to configure stackexchange in this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the name is the last person to edit the question or one of its answers. Editing a comment will not move the question in the queue or change the name in the lower-right corner.

**Added:** As Martin Sleziak comments, what I say above is true when viewing the "active" tab. Viewing with any of the other tabs seems to show the author of the question.

Comment: Thanks:-) My problem is that I cannot decide (only reading the name) which one from the two possibilities.
So the name alone does not give sure information.
(There are some persons whose questions, answers I like to read because I learn a lot of from them.)
So indicating the status(?) of the person would help (at least for me :-) ).

Comment: @vesszabo: The reason that the question was last bumped to the head of the queue is that someone edited the question or one of its answers. That person is the one listed by the question in the queue. Adding more names would either clutter the entry or make the entry taller and push other entries off the front page. If you want to look at someone's questions or answers, you can simply look at the list of questions or answers on their profile page.

Comment: @vesszabo: Occasionally, you get a ghost. That is, the name there has seemingly never been near the thread! I believe that this is because they have had an action which has been un-done, such as posted an answer then deleted it.

Comment: I think it depends on the criteria you use for viewing question. On the [active](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) tab you see the person who was the last to "bump" the question, whereas on the [newest](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) tab you see the asker.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks! That makes perfect sense. I usually use the active tab, but what you say is the logical extension.